# how to create a vertical line with number dots using css?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want thick dots at certain places over the vertical line between [div class="col-md-4"] and [div class="col-md-8"] .

below is what i have tried

```
<div class="col-md-4" style="border-right:1px solid #333;">
<h1>1987</h1><p>lorem ipsom .........</p>
<h1>1990</h1><p>lorem ipsom .........</p>
<h1>1998</h1><p>lorem ipsom .........</p>
</div>

<div class="col-md-8">
description
</div>
```

it created a vertical line between class 4 and class 8 but i also want thick dots over this vertical line for each year. how can i display dots for each year?

Comment: do you want dotted vertical line like this `1987 : 1988` or how you want?

Comment: see, there will be a portion of content in col-md-4 and some portion of content in col-md-8. i want a straight vertical line between them. On this line, there should first dark circle on the vertical line which should be right to the 1987, second dark circle over vertical line right to the 1990 and so on

Comment: so you would like to create a timeline effect, like there are on certain blogs? Provide some code, a code pen sample, a working example of what you would like to work forwards. even your actual code with an image pointing to what you are trying to achieve would do in lack of anything else.

Comment: Yes, I want timeline kind of stuff

Comment: are you trying something like this https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_timeline

Comment: Yes, but I m using bootstrap 4. Anyway, it seems a good source. I m trying that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can structure your HTML like this:

```
<div class="timeline">
    <div class="timeline__item">
        <div class="timeline__item__date"> 1995 </div>
        <div class="timeline__item__text"> lorem ipsom </div>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline__item">
        <div class="timeline__item__date"> 2005 </div>
        <div class="timeline__item__text"> lorem ipsom </div>
    </div>
    ...
</div>
```

And go about applying the CSS like so

```
.timeline__item {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
}

.timeline__item::before {
    /* required for the ::before pseudo-element to be rendered */
    content: '';

    /* positioning the element */
    position: absolute;
    left: 0; top: 50%;
    transform: translate(xvalue , -50%); /* change the xvalue to reposition horizontaly, to be where your 'line' is */

    /* creates the 'color-of-the-text colored circle' */
    width: 5px; height: 5px;
    background-color: currentColor;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

If you want to move the dot from the left side of the `.timeline__item` (where it currently is) to the right, change `.timeline__item::before { left: 0; }` to `.timeline__item::before { right: 0; }`.

This should get you decently started on the right path. If you come back with more specific questions along the line, it will be easier for other users to guide you forward.

Comment: I have a little different scenario but definitely trying your solutions.

Comment: can you tell me, how to create a dark circle using css ":before" ?

Comment: yes, your answer is very close to what i need. Thanks @Andu. I will post the correct answer with my divs and css.

Comment: Thaks Andu, your answer is working with a little modification.